# Determine and unload usb mouser diver

Tags: linux, drivers, usb-device

I've tried to write a simple usb mouse driver, now it's done and I want to test it.
So I need to `rmmod` system's driver and `insmod` mine.

The question is how to determine which exactly driver is handling the mouse now and how to make sure that no one driver handles mouse after unloading.

If it's important my system is Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Run `evtest` as root, select input device for mouse, verify it's the correct one by moving mouse

2) Run `udevadm info -a /dev/input/eventX` with the device from step (1). Look at the output, especially the `DRIVER` lines.

In 99% of the cases your USB mouse will be handled by `hid-generic` and the HID stack in the kernel. See `hidraw.txt`, `hiddev.txt` and `hid-transport.txt` in `linux/Documentation/hid/` in the kernel sources for details how that works.

It's also possible to write a user-space driver using `uhid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/proc/modules` to see that, e.g. `psmouse` is usually the driver loaded by the system. Also, if there is no loaded driver to handle the mouse, the device won't probably work until you load something that does handle it.